# How to create associated object on the has_many relationship using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, has-many

I'm implementing a simple flight-book system using Rails 3.2
But I have a problem when I want to save a order, which may has many passengers.As is to say, they two are one-many relationship.
This is Passenger's model.

```
class Passenger < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accident_number, :cred_number, :cred_type, :delay_number, :name, :order_id
  validates :cred_type, :cred_number, :name, presence: true
  belongs_to :order, :inverse_of => :passengers
end
```

This is Order's model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contact_email, :contact_name, :contact_phone, :flight_id, :print_time, :remark
  validates :contact_email, :contact_name, :contact_phone, :flight_id, :print_time, presence: true

  belongs_to :flight

  has_many :passengers, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :passengers, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :passengers_attributes, :allow_destroy => true

end
```

And the params is like this

```
Parameters: {
"passengers"=>{"new_1"=>{"name"=>"Passenger 1", "cred_type"=>"ID card", 
"cred_number"=>"12345", "accident_number"=>"1", "delay_number"=>"1"},
"new_2"=>{"name"=>"Passenger 2", "cred_type"=>"ID card", "cred_number"=>"54321", "accident_number"=>"1", "delay_number"=>"1"}}, 
"order"=>{"contact_name"=>"Contact 1", "contact_phone"=>"123456", "contact_email"=>"test2@tset,com", "print_time"=>"1", "remark"=>""}, 
"commit"=>"Create Order"}
```

The problem is the order and the passengers can't be saved.
I have tried some ways, but they can't solve it...for example

```
def create                              
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])    

  respond_to do |format|                
    if @order.save                      
      params[:passengers].each do |k, v|
        @order.passengers.create(v)     
      end
```

THANK YOU in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I think if your params had the passengers collection inside of the order hash, you could simply do the following to save:

```
def create                              
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])    
  respond_to do |format|                
    if @order.save
      / something else
    end
  end
end
```

If your relations are setup correctly, you shouldn't need to save your child objects one their own.

Comment: Then what should the params be like? Could you give me a example?

Answer (score 0):

Using accepts_nested_attributes_for should be returning the passenger params within the Order params, using the key `:passengers_attributes`.

You will need to add `:passengers_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` call, and look at why your form is formatting the params hash weirdly. Can you post the view code for the form?

Comment: I used the nested form before, but it didn't work also, I just don't know how to create passengers through the order's Create method.

Comment: My form is like this 'code'%input#new_1_name.input-xlarge{:name => "passengers[new_1][name]", :type => "text"}</blink> then, how to write the right pattern if I want to create more than one passengers?